# How much memory does boost singleton_pool::malloc return?

Tags: c++, boost

My code is segfaulting for some reasons.
Here is the relevant code.

```
typedef boost::singleton_pool<httpHandler,sizeof(httphandler)> httpHandlerpool;
typedef boost::singleton_pool<Conn ,sizeof(Conn)> connpool;


void *httphandler::operator new(size_t size)
{
     return httpHandlerpool::malloc();
}

//there is a corresponding delete as well.    

void *Conn::operator new(size_t size)
{
     return connpool::malloc();
}

//there is a corresponding delete as well.



Conn* httpHandler::getFreeConn()
{
    Conn *c=0;
    c = new Conn(); // 
    memset(c,0,sizeof *c); // This is where looks like some issue is there.
    return c
}
```

In this code when I do a new Conn , how much memory will be allocated? Is it 'sizeof struct Conn`?
What am I doing wrong with memset? Is it necessary?
Thanks.

Comment: What you're missing is that you should almost call e.g. `memset` on objects. Especially if they have virtual member functions.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to `memset`?

Comment: Also, when you do `new Conn` it won't call `httphandler::operator new` _unless_ the `Conn` class inherits from `httphandler`.

Comment: @Pubby : Is memset not necessary? Valgrind was giving a warning `conditional jump depends on uninitialized value` . I should not be doing memset?

Comment: Hmm... What i mean with my first comment is that you should almost **never** call `memset`. The two main reasons is that it will overwrite what the constructor have set (you _do_ use constructors don't you?) and the second is that it will overwrite the virtual function table if the class (or any class it inherits) has virtual functions.